# Difference between different listeners for listview

Tags: android, listview

What is the difference between onClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener and OnItemClickListener for a listview?

Which one should I use for clicking single element in the list?

Edit:

When the item is clicked, it should start a different activity.

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                String Selectitem = item[position];
                Sendthem(Selectitem);
            }
        });

    }

        public void Sendthem(String comp)
        {
            Intent it1 = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
            it1.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,comp);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which one should I use for clicking single element in the list?

OnItemClickListener

Edit:

```
public void Sendthem(String comp)
    {
        Intent it1 = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
        it1.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,comp);
        startActivity(it1); // this is missing
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But for some reason, the listener is not working. If I show you the code, can you help?

Comment: You created the intent, but do NOT use it.

Comment: Sorry did not saw that. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To start a new activity through an intent you need to add the following line:

```
    startActivity(it1);
```

So your code would be:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            String Selectitem = item[position];
            Sendthem(Selectitem);
        }
    });

}

    public void Sendthem(String comp)
    {
        Intent it1 = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
        it1.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,comp);
        startActivity(it1);
    }
```